# sharing git repo for merge / updating code from upstream

Tags: git

I have a git project, which is a submodule and it needs to be updated from upstream. There are two developers working on this submodule, me and another person.

The update using git pull requires us to resolve the merge conflicts. I know some part of the code and he knows the other part, so to resolve the merge, we need to either sit together or find another way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sit together. There is no magic way to resolve half a conflict without committing and pushing broken code which still contains conflict markers.

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so it would be nice if you could accept the answer if it helped or provide your own so other people could benefit from the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try to use

```
git pull --rebase
```

this will allow you to manage smaller hunks and see which particular commits are causing troubles, plus it will make your history streamlined. It will simplify the code discrepancies to the level of each individual commit and therefore should be simple enough for anyone of you to make assumptions about which lines are correct. Then i would recommend to push back the results of the rebase and let the other developer to review the resulting code.
And finally test it of course